# Warning in program

Tags: c

I get this warning if I try to run the code:

warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]

```
!!(((x&0xff)
| ((x >>  8) & 0xff)
| ((x >> 16) & 0xff)
| ((x >> 24) & 0xff))
& 0xaa);
return (x & 0xaaaaaaaa) != 0;
```

The code works fine. I just want to know why the warning is being generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This statement:

```
!!(((x&0xff)
| ((x >>  8) & 0xff)
| ((x >> 16) & 0xff)
| ((x >> 24) & 0xff))
& 0xaa);
```

has no effect because you don't assign the result and there are no side-effects either.

Comment: That might be true, but the code as posted should also generate a `variable not initialized` warning for `x` as well, which means that the code is not complete.

Comment: @KenWhite The code necessarily isn't complete because `x` is not declared anywhere and there is no function to `return` from (both errors). So I am assuming OP is inside a function and `x` is e.g. an integer parameter, in which case the `-Wunused-value` warning is the one that OP would get.

Comment: The variable is initialized before this.